# JWPlayer autodetect best quality for each user without using flash player(HLS, .m3u8) for other browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, amazon-web-services, jwplayer

My videos are hosted on Amazon S3. And am using JW Player7 javascript version.

Amazon has a tool named Elastic Transcoder and via this I transcoded videos with different qualities (1080p,720p,etc...) to .m3u8 format for HLS stream. And now it autodetects well which is the best quality for users.

But it uses flash player to render the video. And flash isn't supported in Mozilla,IE,Opera if you don't have Adobe Flash Player extension installed in your browser?

I want to know is it possible to autodetect right quality with HTML5 player not via Flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JWPlayer runs in the browser and is one of many video players that can be used to play video files in a browser, such as those video files created by Elastic Transcoder. JWPlayer, not Elastic Transcoder, is autodetecting the best video format for the user, based on things like the browser version and the presence of a Flash plugin. [JWPlayer supports HTML5](https://www.jwplayer.com/products/jwplayer/html5-and-flash/).

If you wish to support HTML5 video then you need to configure Elastic Transcoder to generate HTML5 compatible video files (MP4 and WebM) and then [add the URL of your HTML5 compatible video files](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1710454-configuring-multiple-sources) to the list of video sources in the JWPlayer configuration.

Comment: so if I use only HTML5 video in this case is there any way to autodetect best quality(1080,720,480,360,etc...)? @mbaird

Comment: Configuring JWPlayer with files of different quality is documented here http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1428524-hd-quality-toggling